# How to add restrictions on who can delete a wiki page

Tags: 2013, development, publishing-site, publishing-page, enterprise-wiki

We are running an enterprise wiki site collection, now to improve contributions we have defined all users as Contributors to the wiki site, so they can add, edit, delete any wiki pages. And we have restricted certain people with the permission to approve.
But we have run into a problem is that contributor users can (intentionally or by mistake) delete any wiki page, even if they are not the creator.
So can I force this restriction on the wiki page deletion:-

1. Site collection admin & Approver users can delete any wiki page.
2. Contributor user can only delete a wiki page if he is the creator & its version number is 3 or less .version 3 means that the wiki page have been created but never modified by any user.

Can anyone advice on this please?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [create a custom permission level](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263239.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) that does not allow deleting. You'd essentially copy contribute and deselect the delete option. This solves point 1.

For point 2, there isn't really anything that handles this. Item level security settings on lists comes close, but it isn't fully what you need and isn't available in libraries. You'd probably need to roll an event receiver on item deleting and handle logic there.

Comment: but if i simply remove the delete permission from the Contributor group,, then if a user by mistake add a wiki page then he will not be able to delete ...

Comment: There isn't really a permission model to handle what you want. This is about the best you can do without rolling your own in an event receiver.

Comment: ok now i created a copy of the contribute permission level (named it CustomCont), and i un-check the DeleteItem & DeleteVersion check boxes from it. then i assign the "Site Members" group the new permission level (CustomCont) instead of the Contribute. so now the Delete link will be disabled for the Site Member group. but after doing so when contributor users tried to edit the "Page Properties" and they click on save they will receive an error that this list has not been shared with you.

Comment: now if i return the permission to its old setting , then site Memebers can edit the page properties again. so why un-chekcing the Delete permission level, will prevent users from modifying the page properties !!! do u have any idea ?

Comment: It might depend on what properties they are trying to delete. If they are renaming the page, that could be constituted as a delete and prevent it.

Comment: yes they try to rename the page ,,, so now i can conclude if users want to rename a wiki page they need to have delete permission !!!! come on sharepoint ,, what a bug is this!!!

Comment: Again, this has been around for as long as I can remember. Renames of files are essentially deletes and add as new.

Comment: OMG so how i can handle this? i can not mention to the management  that contributor users can not rename wiki pages , if we need to prevent them from deleting wiki pages...

Comment: wiki page renames are just like renaming an aspx page or file name, these tend to be static and it seems more like they should be editing a title field and not the page name.

Comment: but what if we need to modify the name , i mean to modify the  URL itself to be consistent with the title !!